# Unit Test Explorer does not show up Async Unit Tests for metro apps

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-metro, async-await

Not sure this is a known issue. I’m using VS2012 RC (Ultimate), and Win8 Release Preview. I have created a Unit Test Library (metro style app), and wrote a Unit Test, which include async/await keywords. However when I compile the Unit Test project, Unit Test Explorer does not show up the Test I wrote. If I exclude the async/await keywords, then the Unit Test Explorer shows up in the Test I just wrote. Has anyone come across with this before, or is it just me?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async void SomeAsyncTest()
    {
        var result = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("some file path");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you make the method return a `Task`?

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if mstest is filtering methods within the class incorrectly or if the async keyword alters the signature such that it doesn't appear through reflection.

Comment: svick, you right. Task makes it appear in the UTE.

Comment: @Raj: `async void` unit tests are not supported (yet). They don't work correctly. Asynchronous unit tests *must* be `async Task`.

Comment: @svick Can you please add your comment as the answer to this question? Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78895/how-to-handle-an-answer-as-a-comment - Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unit test methods that are `async` have to return `Task`, not `void`.

That's because `async void` methods are hard to track: there is no easy way for the unit testing library to find out that the test completed. (It's hard, but I think it's not impossible. You could do this by using a custom `SynchronizationContext`.)